# How to process a directive AFTER it's HTML is loaded (using jQuery Datatables)?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

The angular app has been embedded in a jquery app which uses data-tables plugin to display tables.
In this table, HTML for buttons and links is generated after the page is loaded and the server side AJAX call is completed.

I've written an attribute level directive `my-directive` which is applied to those generated HTML buttons.
like `<button my-directive>delete</button>`

Since the HTML is generated AFTER the Angular APP is initialized, the `my-directive` attribute is not effective.

How can I process the directive after the AJAX call is complete?

(I'm capturing the event of AJAX call completion from datatable's `drawCallback` method.

Comment: Instead of letting us guess out of the blue, please show your code

Comment: @davidkonrad : related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648788/datatabes-how-to-get-pagination-working-when-table-html-is-compiled-with-angul

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

1. Re-compile the HTML generated by the data-table using Angular.
2. Replace the HTML with the compiled version.

For this, we should add the following code to data-tables configuration --

```
 var exampleTable = $("#table_id").DataTable({
 "drawCallback": function( settings ) {

            angular.element(document).injector().invoke(['$compile', function ($compile) {
                    // Create a scope.
                    var $scope = angular.element(document.body).scope();
                    // Specify what it is we'll be compiling.
                    var to_compile = $("#table_id").html();
                    // Compile the tag, retrieving the compiled output.
                    var $compiled = $compile(to_compile)($scope);
                    // Ensure the scope and been signalled to digest our data.
                    $scope.$digest();
                    // Replace the compiled output to the page.
                    $("#table_id").html($compiled);
                }])

        }
```